# How to conditionally merge two rows with multiple values together and mutate in R?

Tags: r, conditional-statements, dplyr, case-when

Fish have been caught using different fishing methods.

I would like to merge rows based on `Species` (that's if they are the same fish species), if they are caught by both `Bottom fishing` and `Trolling` methods it will result in two rows collapsing into one row, changing the `Method` value to `Both`.

For example `Caranx ignobilis` will have a new `Method` value of `Both`. `Bait` `Released` and `Kept` columns should also have values on the same row.

```
          Species                  Method       Bait     Released  Kept
        4 Caranx ignobilis         Both         NA       1         1
```

It seems so simple yet I have been scratching my head for hours and toying around with `case_when` as part of the `tidyverse` package.

The tibble is a result of previously sub-setting data using `group_by` and `pivot_wider`.

***This is what the sample looks like:***

```
# A tibble: 10 x 5
# Groups:   Species [9]
   Species                  Method          Bait Released  Kept
   <chr>                    <fct>          <int>    <int> <int>
 1 Aethaloperca rogaa       Bottom fishing    NA       NA     2
 2 Aprion virescens         Bottom fishing    NA       NA     1
 3 Balistidae spp.          Bottom fishing    NA       NA     1
 4 Caranx ignobilis         Trolling          NA       NA     1
 5 Caranx ignobilis         Bottom fishing    NA        1    NA
 6 Epinephelus fasciatus    Bottom fishing    NA        3    NA
 7 Epinephelus multinotatus Bottom fishing    NA       NA     5
 8 Other species            Bottom fishing    NA        1    NA
 9 Thunnus albacares        Trolling          NA       NA     1
10 Variola louti            Bottom fishing    NA       NA     1
```

***Data:***

```
fish_catch <- structure(list(Species = c("Aethaloperca rogaa", "Aprion virescens","Balistidae spp.", "Caranx ignobilis", "Caranx ignobilis", "Epinephelus fasciatus","Epinephelus multinotatus", "Other species", "Thunnus albacares","Variola louti"),
              Method = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L,1L, 1L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("Bottom fishing", "Trolling"), class = "factor"),Bait = c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_,NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_,NA_integer_),
              Released = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, 3L, NA, 1L,NA, NA),
              Kept = c(2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, NA, NA, 5L, NA, 1L, 1L)), class = c("grouped_df","tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -10L), groups = structure(list(Species = c("Aethaloperca rogaa", "Aprion virescens",
              "Balistidae spp.","Caranx ignobilis", "Epinephelus fasciatus", "Epinephelus multinotatus","Other species", "Thunnus albacares", "Variola louti"), .rows = list(1L, 2L, 3L, 4:5, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L)), row.names = c(NA,-9L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = FALSE))
```

The route I was going down but then I realised it's not incorporating `Species` or the other columns

```
    mutate(Method = case_when(Method == "Bottom fishing" & Method == "Trolling" ~ "Both",
                                 Method == "Bottom fishing" ~ "Bottom fishing",
                                 Method == "Trolling" ~ "Trolling", TRUE ~ as.character(MethodCaught)))
```

Comment: What value should be used for the other columns? Could you please indicate how the row regarding `Caranx ignobilis` should look like?

Comment: Caranx ignobilis caught by 'Trolling' and 'Kept' (n=1) and the second Caranx ignobilis was caught 'Bottom Fishing' and 'Released' (n=1). Column should read as 'Bait' NA 'Released' 1 'Kept' 1. Edited question @nicola

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one approach using `tidyverse`. You can `group_by(Species)` and set `Method` to "Both" if both Bottom fishing and Trolling are included in Method within that Species. Then afterwards, you can `group_by` both Species and Method, and use `fill` to replace `NA` with known values. In the end, use `slice` to keep one row for each Species/Method. This assumes you would have otherwise 1 row for each Species/Method - please let me know if this is not the case.

```
library(tidyverse)

fish_catch %>%
  group_by(Species) %>%
  mutate(Method = ifelse(all(c("Bottom fishing", "Trolling") %in% Method), "Both", as.character(Method))) %>%
  group_by(Species, Method) %>%
  fill(c(Bait, Released, Kept), .direction = "updown") %>%
  slice(1)
```

**Output**

```
# A tibble: 9 x 5
# Groups:   Species, Method [9]
  Species                  Method          Bait Released  Kept
  <chr>                    <chr>          <int>    <int> <int>
1 Aethaloperca rogaa       Bottom fishing    NA       NA     2
2 Aprion virescens         Bottom fishing    NA       NA     1
3 Balistidae spp.          Bottom fishing    NA       NA     1
4 Caranx ignobilis         Both              NA        1     1
5 Epinephelus fasciatus    Bottom fishing    NA        3    NA
6 Epinephelus multinotatus Bottom fishing    NA       NA     5
7 Other species            Bottom fishing    NA        1    NA
8 Thunnus albacares        Trolling          NA       NA     1
9 Variola louti            Bottom fishing    NA       NA     1
```

Comment: real nice works perfectly, thank you @ben yes the `slice(1)` is needed. Could `case_when` be implemented instead of `ifelse`?

Comment: Glad to hear. With regards to `case_when` would be interested to know more details and specifics. But the equivalent might be something like: `mutate(Method = case_when(
    all(c("Bottom fishing", "Trolling") %in% Method) ~ "Both",
    TRUE ~ as.character(Method)
  ))`

Answer (score 0):

This should get you started. You can add the other columns to the summarize function.

```
library(tidyverse)    
fish_catch %>% select(-Bait, -Released, -Kept) %>%
  group_by(Species) %>%
  summarize(Method = paste0(Method, collapse = "")) %>%
  mutate(Method = fct_recode(Method, "both" = "TrollingBottom fishing"))

# A tibble: 9 x 2
  Species                  Method        
  <chr>                    <fct>         
1 Aethaloperca rogaa       Bottom fishing
2 Aprion virescens         Bottom fishing
3 Balistidae spp.          Bottom fishing
4 Caranx ignobilis         both          
5 Epinephelus fasciatus    Bottom fishing
6 Epinephelus multinotatus Bottom fishing
7 Other species            Bottom fishing
8 Thunnus albacares        Trolling      
9 Variola louti            Bottom fishing
```

Comment: @JL_sey no, ofc you should use a sum function or whatever math operation you'd like to do